# hosts file manipulation with username

Tags: windows, apache, hosts

I can do this basic manipulation

```
123.123.123.123 domain.com
123.123.123.123 www.domain.com
```

I tried the following

```
123.123.123.123/~username/ domain.com
123.123.123.123/~username/ www.domain.com
```

it does not work, I need to do it with that username directory because the host does not provide specific IP assigned to the domain (which could of made my life easier) is there away to show the domain `www.domain.com` name provided I type `123.123.123.123/~username/` on the browser.

Many thanks

Comment: please let me know the details of the server used

Comment: Please let me know the details of the server you need, to know...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hosts file can be used only to resolve netbios computer names and domain names - URLs are not accepted. Also, this file only affects the computer the file is on - the changes do not apply to any other device.

To do that kind of redirection, you would need to configure the server to point the domain to that website.

If the domain works and you wish to change the address in the browser's address bar when the user enters http://123.123.123.123/~username/ as address, you could create a redirection via .htaccess or PHP to the address you wish to use.